# solving congruence class equation

Tags: abstract-algebra

How would I go about solving a problem like this:

Find all $ [a] $ for which $ [a] \odot x = [1] $ has a solution in $Z_4$

Having trouble with the abstractness of congruence classes.

Comment: Care to define your notation for us? Is the circle multiplication mod 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the multiplication you've denoted is just multiplication mod 4, it can be shown:

$ \gcd(x,y)=1 $ if and only if $\exists$ $c \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $cx \equiv 1$ (mod $y$). Thus, $[a]$ satisfies your condition if and only if $\gcd(a,4)=1$. Then assuming $a \in \mathbb{Z}_4$ (as we should), we have $a=1$ or $a=3$.